# Optional closures in Swift protocols

Tags: ios, swift, oop

Let's say that I have a protocol and a class conforming to this protocol.

```
protocol Foo {
    func task(success: (() -> Void)?)
}

class Bar: Foo {
    func task(success: (() -> Void)?) {
        //DO STUFF
    }
}
```

Success closure is an optional, because not every call will require it. For example, this is a common situation when calling such function from an unit test, because we want to fulfill expectation in the success closure, while in a regular call success closure is not needed for some reason.

Since functions defined in protocols cannot have default values for their parameters, for each call to task on object conforming to `Foo`, We have to call it with the closure or pass explicitly nil as the closure value:

```
var obj: Foo
obj = Bar()
obj.task(nil) //CLOSURE VALUE SET TO nil
obj.task() {} //EMPTY CLOSURE
obj.task() //NOT ALLOWED
```

What is a recommended method to implement such a structure? Do we need to pass empty closures every time, or calling functions with closure value set to nil, or is there another way to deal with it?

Comment: Why is that ugly? There are plenty of instances where you might pass nil into the completion block of apple's methods. Such as `vc.navigationController.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true, completion:nil)` It just simply means you don't want to do anything after the task is completed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as Primarily Opinion-Based because answers can only be based on personal opinion, not fact. `What is a recommended method to implement such a structure? For me passing an empty closures every time, or calling functions with closure value set to nil is kind of ugly.`  What is ugly to you or recommended by someone else is not fact.

Comment: @JAL my opinion is not important here, I wanted to ask if there is a better way to implement such a structure. I'll edit the question and remove this sentence

Comment: Define "better."  Your question is still subjective.

Comment: @JAL the question is edited and there it's no personal opinion there

Comment: The question is still off topic because you ask for a "recommended method" which is based on user preference, not fact.

Comment: @JAL for me it's on point. Maybe the recommended method is the one I provided, I don't know and that's why I asked

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation:

Instead of this:

```
protocol Foo {
    func task(success: (() -> Void)?)
}
```

Use this:

```
protocol Foo {
    func task(success: () -> Void)
}
```

You can always pass an empty closure if you don't need to handle task completion. Optional closures just make your code's intent less clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can implement. The = nil may not be necessary but I haven't tested.

```
func doSomething(closure:(()->Void)? = nil) {
     closure?()
}
```

Comment: When the object is of type Foo, which is a protocol, it doesn't know that the function in a particular implementation has a default parameter set

Comment: maybe it does not need to know.